# iOS - how to get rid of cocoapods if there are already some references in them?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Here is how my Cocoapods project looks like:

[image: pods setup]

I am getting a linker error when I try to archive this project and I think it might be simplest to just get rid of pods.

How can I get rid of pods while putting the necessary items inside it back under the project structure?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably better to figure out how to solve linker errors.  Just my opinion, though…

Comment: I agree with Aaron. Not using CocoaPods will in general make linker errors harder to diagnose and fix, not easier. That said, the linked duplicate has some info on how to do it.

Comment: Actually if you take a close look at the screenshot, on the top-left it just points to not being able to find the pods library, and highlights it in red. Are there just steps to make those items not red?